# Using Append without creating variable

Tags: list-manipulation, programming

If I use the Append command as follows,

```
Append[foo,1];
```

I will get an error that says

```
Append::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Append[foo,1].
```

The solution I use to avoid this is to define my list as an empty list early in my code:

```
foo1={};
foo2={};
(* 

A break where there may be a ton of code, maybe some loops


*)
foo1=Append[foo1,1];
foo2=Append[foo2,1];
```

This works fine of course, but I end up with a bunch of {} lines at the begging of my code, before the loops and other stuff.

Is there a way to use append for a list that is not yet defined?

Comment: `foo1 = foo2 = {};` might be more compact?

Comment: Have you looked at the `Sow` and `Reap` functions?

Comment: As hinted at by @Ruud3.1415, it's quite likely that there are better ways to do whatever it is you're trying to do. The construction that you're using is standard in procedural languages, but it is not idiomatic in *Mathematica*, and usually you can do things much faster and simpler using a functional method. In other words, [try to avoid loops in *Mathematica*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/alternatives-to-procedural-loops-and-iterating-over-lists-in-mathematica).

Comment: One more note: if you're going to `Append` to a variable (sometimes it's convenient for a one-off addition to a list), you might as well use `AppendTo`, which is more concise.

Comment: You could also use linked lists as a more efficient way of appending elements to a data structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid initializing any of your lists, you may wish to consider defining `myAppend` as follows:

```
Clear[myAppend]
myAppend[foo_List, stuff_] := Append[foo, stuff]
myAppend[foo_Symbol, stuff_] := {stuff}
```

You would then use `myAppend` instead of `Append`, with initialized lists or with uninitialized symbols, as in the this example:

```
Clear[foo1, foo2]
foo1 = {1, 2, 3};

myAppend[foo1, "a"]
myAppend[foo2, "b"]
```

`myAppend` returns a list in both cases, so it could be used instead of `Append` in your example.  `myAppend` does not clobber existing lists.

Your example contains instances where you actually performing something like an `AppendTo` the list.  That is, you are replacing the old list with  the updated list.  Here is an example of a `myAppendTo` function that will append the new data and replace your old list with the new one:

```
Clear[myAppendTo]
SetAttributes[myAppendTo, HoldFirst]
myAppendTo[foo_, stuff_] := (foo = myAppend[foo, stuff];)

Clear[foo1, foo2]
foo1 = {1, 2, 3};

myAppendTo[foo1, "a"]
myAppendTo[foo2, "b"]

{foo1, foo2}

(*  {{1, 2, 3, "a"}, {"b"}}  *)
```

Notice that `myAppendTo` does not return a value, but it does replace the old list, if any, with the new list.

Answer (score 4):

I would do something like:

```
{foo1,foo2}=Last[Reap[
(* 

A break where there may be a ton of code, maybe some loops


*)
Sow[1,tag1];
Sow[1,tag2];
,{tag1,tag2}]];
```